# CSS sprites & iOS 4.3 or lower

Tags: css, ios, sprite

I'm currently working on a site which needs to be presented well on iOS devices, primarily iPads. Everything works fine apart from anything using a sprite as a background image. The height/width is precise and works in every browser, but with iOS version 4.3.2 and below I get the following:

Here is the CSS for those two elements:

```
#masthead > a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin: 23px 80px 20px 5px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 235px;
  height: 20px;
  background: url(../../img/sprite.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

And this is the sprite sheet:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like image bleeding. You should leave some empty space between the images in your sprite.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/646981/567986

Comment: That's perfect, thank you very much! I didn't realise there was a problem with zooming on the iPad and stuff. It makes a lot of sense.

Comment: You have the same problem in desktop browsers if you zoom. But most people don't zoom on desktop, as opposed to tablets.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it could be an `overflow` issue.

Try adding:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Is there a live URL that we could have a look at?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a URL I can show you at the moment. The overflow:hidden; fix didn't work sorry.

Comment: `line-height:0; font-size: 0;` ?